# Using an ImmutableJS Object as the React Component State

Tags: reactjs, immutability, setstate

I am trying to use ImmutableJS to help maintain state in a React component. I can use it just fine if the state *contains* an immutable object. But, if the *entire* state is an immutable object, then it fails whenever I try to *setState()* with an error that says

> TypeError: this.state.get is not a function.

Below is a minimal example to reproduce the error. Every time the *increment* button is pushed, the count variable should be incremented and re-rendered. Please help me understand why this approach does not work. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map as ImmutableMap } from 'immutable'

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = ImmutableMap({ count: 0 }) // entire state is immutable
  }

  increment () {
    const newCount = this.state.get('count') + 1
    this.setState(prevState => prevState.set('count', newCount))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.get('count') } // produces error after setState()
        <button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this part](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) of the docs.

> When you call setState(), React merges the object you provide into the
> current state.

So after `setState` you'll be left with an empty object.

From [Immutable.js documentation](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state):

> Note that state must be a plain JS object, and not an Immutable
> collection, because React's setState API expects an object literal and
> will merge it (Object.assign) with the previous state.

In the current version of the code, the actual merging of the state occcurs in [ReactUpdateQueue.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactUpdateQueue.js) within the `getStateFromUpdate` function with the following line:

```
  // Merge the partial state and the previous state.
  return Object.assign({}, prevState, partialState);
```